# Getting an exception when calling vector.erase() cpp

Tags: c++, exception, opencv

I'm working with OpenCV2.4.5 on windows 8 and VS2012.

I'm getting a strange exception when calling erase on a vector. Here is my code, the exception is in the last line:

```
FINGERTIP_API int PalmTrackingProcess(
    const Mat& I_ycbcr, 
    Mat& I_depth, 
    sFTHistory& history, 
    sFTResult& result)
{
    static int gilcount=0;
    gilcount++;
    //function [success, results, vars] = PalmTrackingProcess(YCBCR, Depth, vars)
        //    if vars.frame_i==300    % 300 5fingers     480 1finger     400 spread 
        //    vars.frame_i;
        //end
        //
        //% RGB = ycbcr2rgb(double(YCBCR/255));
        //% RGB = colorspace('RGB<-YCbCr',double(YCBCR));
        //results.success = 1;
    result.success = true;
    //success = 1;
    bool success = true;
    //results.Palm1 = [];
    result.Palm1 = 0;
    //results.Palm2 = [];
    result.Palm2 = 0;
    //
    //SEdepth = vars.SEdepth;
    Mat SEdepth = history.SEdepth;
    //Gaussian = vars.Gaussian;
    Mat Gaussian = history.Gaussian;
    //BWpalmFilt = vars.BWpalmFilt;
    Mat BWpalmFilt = history.BWpalmFilt;
    //% Gaussian3D = vars.Gaussian3D;
    Mat Gaussian3D = history.Gaussian3D;
    //peak2valleyRatio = vars.peak2valleyRatio;
    double peak2valleyRatio = history.peak2valleyRatio;
    //% SE1 = vars.SE1;
    //% image_object.RGB = RGB;
    //% image_object.YCBCR = YCBCR/255;
    //image_object.Depth = Depth;
    //
    //
    //%% Foreground Mask segmentation
    //% foregroundMask = ForegroundDetectorMask( RGB,vars.foregroundDetector);
    //% foregroundMask = imopen(foregroundMask,vars.SE1);
    //% foregroundMask = imclose(foregroundMask,vars.SEskin);
    //% foregroundMask = imopen(foregroundMask,vars.SEskin);
    //% Mask = find(imfill(foregroundMask,'holes'));
    //% third_dim_add = size(Depth,1) * size(Depth,2);
    //% image_object.foreRGB = zeros(size(RGB),'single');
    //% image_object.foreRGB([Mask; (Mask+third_dim_add); (Mask+2*third_dim_add)]) = RGB([Mask; (Mask+third_dim_add); (Mask+2*third_dim_add)]);
    //% image_object.foreDepth = 2047*ones(size(Depth),'single'); 
    //% image_object.foreDepth(Mask) = Depth(Mask); 
    //% Mask = find(ones(size(Depth)));

    // Depth(350:end,:) = 2047; Gidi UDPATE: 27.12.2013


    for(int i = 0; i < I_depth.rows; i++)
    {
        unsigned short* I_depth0 = I_depth.ptr<unsigned short>(i);

        for(int j = 349; j < I_depth.cols; j++)
        {
            I_depth0[j] = 2047;
        }
    }

    //Mask = find(Depth<vars.maxSkinDepth);
    assert(I_depth.isContinuous());

    int size = I_depth.rows * I_depth.cols;
    int* tmp = new int[size];
    int count = 0;

    const unsigned short* I_depthPtr = I_depth.ptr<unsigned short>(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(I_depthPtr[i] < history.maxSkinDepth)
        {
            tmp[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
    }

    Mat mask(count, 1, CV_32S, tmp);

    //
    //
    //%% Skin Tone Segmentation (need to implement training and improved covariance)
    //[SkinMask,h,s,v,vars]=SegmentSkin(YCBCR,Mask,vars);
    Mat skinMask;
    Mat h, s, v;
    SegmentSkin(I_ycbcr, mask, history, skinMask, h, s, v); 

    mask.release();
    delete [] tmp;

    //% image_object.colorFiltDepth(SkinMask) = Depth(SkinMask);
    //% image_object.colorFiltRGB = zeros(size(RGB),'single');
    //% image_object.colorFiltRGB([SkinMask; (SkinMask+third_dim_add); (SkinMask+2*third_dim_add)]) = RGB([SkinMask; (SkinMask+third_dim_add); (SkinMask+2*third_dim_add)]);
    //
    //
    //%% Depth Segmentation 
    //depthHist = histc(Depth(SkinMask),100:1000);
    double minDepth = 0;
    double maxDepth = 0;
    int skinMaskSize = 0;
    int* skinMask0 = 0;
    const unsigned short* I_depth0 = I_depth.ptr<unsigned short>(0);
    if(!skinMask.empty())
    {
        assert(skinMask.isContinuous() && I_depth.isContinuous());
        skinMaskSize = skinMask.rows * skinMask.cols;
        skinMask0 = skinMask.ptr<int>(0);
        int* skinDepthAr = new int[skinMaskSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < skinMaskSize; i++)
        {
            skinDepthAr[i] = I_depth0[skinMask0[i]];
        }
        Mat skinDepth(1, skinMaskSize, CV_32S, skinDepthAr);

        Mat depthHist = MatlabFunctions::histc(skinDepth, 100, 1000);

        skinDepth.release();
        delete [] skinDepthAr;

        //% test = conv(depthHist,1/10*[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ]','same');
        //minDepth = find(depthHist>80,1,'first') + 90;

        double depthHistLength = depthHist.cols * depthHist.rows;
        const unsigned short* depthHist0 = depthHist.ptr<unsigned short>(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < depthHistLength; i++)
        {
            if(depthHist0[i] > 80)
            {
                minDepth = i + 91.0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //if isempty(minDepth)
    if(!minDepth)
    {
        //maxDepth = NaN; minDepth = NaN; 
        minDepth = numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
        //vars.maxSkinDepth = 1000;
        history.maxSkinDepth = 1000;
    }
    //else
    else
    {
        //maxDepth = minDepth+75;
        maxDepth = minDepth + 50;
        //vars.maxSkinDepth = minDepth+100;
        //history.maxSkinDepth = minDepth + 100;
        //end
    }
    //% figure(1) % Histogram of skin pixels
    //% area(100:1000,depthHist);
    //% hold on
    //% plot(minDepth,1, 'or','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','g')
    //% plot(maxDepth,1, 'or','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','g')
    //% hold off
    //DepthMask = SkinMask((Depth(SkinMask)>minDepth & Depth(SkinMask)<maxDepth)   );%   | Depth(SkinMask)==0
    //  DepthMaskMorph = false(size(Depth));
    //DepthMaskMorph(DepthMask) = true;
    Mat DepthMaskMorph(I_depth.rows, I_depth.cols, CV_8U, Scalar::all(0));
    int* depthMaskAr = 0;
    if(skinMaskSize)
        depthMaskAr = new int[skinMaskSize];

    unsigned char* DepthMaskMorph0 = DepthMaskMorph.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
    count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < skinMaskSize; i++)
    {
        unsigned short val = I_depth0[skinMask0[i]];
        if(val > minDepth && val < maxDepth)
        {
            depthMaskAr[count] = skinMask0[i];
            DepthMaskMorph0[skinMask0[i]] = 1;
            count++;
        }
    }

    auto mat_deleter = [](Mat * m){delete [] m->data; m->release(); delete m;};
    std::unique_ptr<Mat, decltype(mat_deleter)> depthMatToPalmAndFingers(new Mat(1, count, CV_32S, depthMaskAr), mat_deleter);

    //imshow("Test", DepthMaskMorph.t() * 255);
    //waitKey(0);

    //Mat DepthMask(1, count, CV_32S, depthMaskAr);
    //  const int * currentRow = mask.ptr<int >(0);
    //DepthMaskMorph = imclose(DepthMaskMorph,SEdepth);
    Mat DepthMaskMorphClosed;

    morphologyEx(DepthMaskMorph, DepthMaskMorphClosed, MORPH_CLOSE, SEdepth);

    //imshow("Test", DepthMaskMorphClosed.t() * 255);
    //waitKey(0);

    //DepthMaskMorph = imfill(DepthMaskMorph,'holes');
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Mat tmpImage(DepthMaskMorphClosed.rows, DepthMaskMorphClosed.cols, CV_8U);
    DepthMaskMorphClosed.copyTo(tmpImage);
    findContours( tmpImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    // skipping parent contours
    int index = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    for (auto it = hierarchy.cbegin(); it != hierarchy.cend(); it++)
    {
        if (((*it)[2] != -1) && ((*it)[3] == -1))
        {
            contours.erase(contours.begin() + index - offset); //<== EXCEPTION
            offset++;
        }
        index ++;
    }
```

I'm getting an exception when index=19 and offset=0. I also get an exception when trying:

EDIT: this is the exception I'm getting:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000007F8CAAABD59 (ntdll.dll) in FingerTipTest.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x000007F8CAB005F0).
```

I have no idea how this could even happen. Can someone point me as to what can cause it?

Thanks,

Gil.

Comment: What is the name of the exception?

Comment: You'll get an exception here iff contours.size() <= 1.

Comment: I guess maybe also if the move constructor of the class throws an exception, but that would be crazy

Comment: First, please follow [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) when posting questions.  90% of the code you posted is irrelevant to the question.  Second, what is the size of `contours` when you get out of the `findContours` function?  Debugging and stepping through your code will likely find the error much faster than us trying to figure out what the functions you haven't shown actually do.

Comment: @Zac Howland, the size of contours is 36.

I'm not new to C++ programming.I did everything I can trying to debug the code and fixing this exception. I'm not just asking you guys to do my work, I really haven't got clue.

Answer (score 1):

I would try iterating over hierarchy backwards (start with rbegin() and move down to rend())
This is generally safer and simpler when erasing vector entries.
I am not sure it will solve your problem but it will simplify the code and make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the exception disappeared when I changed it to work with OpenCV 2.4.7

Answer (score -1):

You are adding 1 to a random_access iterator, which could even be a pointer itself depending on the implementation you are using.  Why not try:

```
vector<vector<Point> >::iterator it = contours.begin();
std::advance(it, 1);
contours.erase(it);
```

This should also work:

```
contours.erase(++contours.begin());
```

You should probably add code to check the size before erasing from a position that is not the beginning or end of the container.

Comment: I tried    contours.erase(std::advance(contours.begin() ,1+ index - offset)); but it doesn't compile - cannot convert parameter 1 from void to std::Vector_const_iterator<_MyVec>.

Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I made an error in the code with std::advance - it doesn't return the advanced iterator but modifies it in place.